# how to iterate over firestore document id in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, iterator, iteration

I have returned all the IDs of my firestore documents, and now I need to get the index of each one.
Until now I get an error: "Spread elements in a list or set literals must implement 'Iterable' "
So, How can I iterate over it?

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('prova')
    .get()
    .then((QuerySnapshot querySnapshot) {
  querySnapshot.docs.forEach((doc) {
    print(doc.id);
     //this next line gives me error
    var a = <String>{...doc.id};
    print(a);

  });
});
```

**Output:**

I/flutter (29392): G0luyVnh1ahW5bfSqh8k 
I/flutter (29392): V7ts6hEYqQiM4creal1O 
I/flutter (29392): Xf3zzLzBzF3dzQ4OT9oO 
I/flutter (29392): iKSjc3HQCAvzmaCMpFcg 
I/flutter (29392): jxHT2TwMTfRf8SjbidK2

[image]

Comment: are you trying to print the JSON contet of each document?

Comment: No, i would like to iterate the array of IDs, with a for loop, or anything so i can get the index of each ID.

Comment: Have you gone through this stackoverflow [link1] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61065524/use-spread-operator-on-object-with-type-safety-in-dart)